# Postgres trigger function if statement on jsonb array

Tags: postgresql, if-statement, jsonb

I'm trying to insert into another table if a user has a certain role. The roles are currently stored on the user object as a json array `[{'type': 'ADMIN'}]`

My code is as follows

```
BEGIN
    IF NEW.roles->'type' @> '"ADMIN"' THEN
        // INSERT INTO new_table
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
```

The row never gets inserted if the role is there. Is there a way to do IF statements on jsonb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `roles` is an array, you need to test for an array element:

```
IF NEW.roles @> '[{"type": "ADMIN"}]'
```

Alternatively, if you know the array only contains a single element, you can access the value by index:

```
IF NEW.roles -> 0 ->> 'type' = 'ADMIN'
```